# VBA 'Scripting.Dictionary' on a MAC

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code on a VBA spreadsheet (which works perfect on a PC):

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each rCell In ws.Range("meals", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If Not .Exists(rCell.value) Then
        .Add rCell.value, Nothing
    End If
Next rCell

cbMeal.List = .Keys
End With
```

Is there a way to get it to work on the MAC?

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Comment: The for each bug at https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary/issues/17 is preventing me from using this.

Comment: If you want to use `For Each` then you can pull out either the keys or the values (as variant array) and iterate over those ?  I don't have a Mac to test though.

Comment: Having to explicitly iterate the values is a minor hinderance IMO, not a showstopper at all. It even improves readability, by making your code more explicit about what's going on. I don't see how that issue could be "preventing" you from using it. Now looking at your code... what's the use of a dictionary, if the value you're storing is `Nothing`? Preventing duplicates in `cbMeal.List`? How many rows are being iterated, and how many different values are there (i.e. what's the size of the data)?