# Mac Excel 2016 "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object"

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a large data of website scraped data (all configurable products with multiple colour and sizes) which I need to convert to a format which can be uploaded to a Magento website and I want to use Excel (Mac) to step by step convert the data from the scraped format to the Magento import format. I am trying to extract a list of unique products item code from the scraped original data so I can search and extract first each product and then convert each product to the required format through macros and VBA. Since the data is so large doing each product manually will take month to complete conversion of the data.

I tried to extract the unique values using the suggestion given in [Quicker way to get all unique values of a column in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044556/quicker-way-to-get-all-unique-values-of-a-column-in-vba) from another article in stackoverflow.com

since I am using it in Mac Excel i receive the error

Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't create object

Is there any one who can suggest how to get rid of this error and get the unique values in another sheet or can some one suggest a method to extract a range of product data based on the item code to another excel sheet. I am a newbie to excel VBA and macros programming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249572/vba-scripting-dictionary-on-a-mac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869266/vba-excel-dictionary-on-mac

Comment: Also if you have any activeX controls then you will get that error. Replace them with Form controls